# Flex-wrap: wrap - image + wrapper with width 100%

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, flexbox

Is it possible to have a wrapper with a width of `100%` inside a `flex-wrap: wrap;` wrapper and only make the `flex-wrap: wrap;` effect take place if the wrapper with `100%` is smaller than x amount of pixels?

Sample site [here](http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/TESTING_SAMPLES/index.php)

```css
.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.innerWrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.facebook1 {
  background-color: #3a559f;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.twitter1 {
  background-color: #50abf1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.google1 {
  background-color: #dc4e41;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}

.innerWrapper2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sample 1 flex-wrap wrap</h2>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <img src="http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/VIGTIG/LOGIN/loginAdminBackup8/uploads/pernille_8.jpg" alt="some image">
  <div class="innerWrapper1">
    <div class="facebook1"></div>
    <div class="twitter1"></div>
    <div class="google1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>No flex-wrap wrap but what i want</h2>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <img src="http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/VIGTIG/LOGIN/loginAdminBackup8/uploads/pernille_8.jpg" alt="some image">
  <div class="innerWrapper2">
    <div class="facebook1"></div>
    <div class="twitter1"></div>
    <div class="google1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-width maybe ??? your code sample should be here , you can even build a working snippet  here via the icon that looks alike : `[<>]`.   .... to avoid to be downvoted or closed ;)

Comment: Okay i will try to make the code sample here, i havent done that before.. well the wrapper which is right to an image should have a width of 100% and only the outer wrapper should flex-wrap wrap when the inner wrapper is x amount of pixels

Comment: looks a bit weird in the code sample on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min-width` can be used as a break point and flex boxes can be imbricated.

Some updates:
*`min-width` will wrap element everytime division of `300px` is reach.*

*Ff 3 elements are set to `min-width: 300px`, one will drop at `900px`, next one at `600px`, then scrollbar will show once `300px` is reached.*

Update made to your code

```
.wrapper1 > img,
.innerWrapper1 {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.innerWrapper1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.innerWrapper1 > div {
  flex: 1;
}

.facebook1,
.twitter1,
.google1 {
   min-height: 50px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper1 > img,
.innerWrapper1 {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.innerWrapper1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.innerWrapper1 > div {
  flex: 1;
}

.facebook1 {
  background-color: #3a559f;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.twitter1 {
  background-color: #50abf1;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.google1 {
  background-color: #dc4e41;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  color: #dc4e41;
  background: lightgreen;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 1px gold, 0 0 2px black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sample 1 flex-wrap wrap + break point at average 640px via min-width:320px</h2>
<h3>load on full page mode to test behavior/breakpoint</h3>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <img src="http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/VIGTIG/LOGIN/loginAdminBackup8/uploads/pernille_8.jpg" alt="some image">
  <div class="innerWrapper1">
    <div class="facebook1"></div>
    <div class="twitter1"></div>
    <div class="google1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
imbricate flexbox involved
```

[codepen to play with, it has been updated from comments below where only img gets `min-width`](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GEzKbY)

Comment: Well what i want is that the wrapper is aligned to the right of the image, and only flex-wrap wrap when the wrapper is etc min 300px

Comment: @Javaish 300px ? then set min-width at 150px , this should do the job test and play here https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bRzbgx

Comment: But it does not flex-wrap wrap when getting under the 300/150px? :) it is supposed to flex-wrap wrap when the wrapper gets under x amount of pixels, it is because it will be dynamic pictures with different lengths, and when an image makes the wrapper less than x amount of pixels it should flex wrap wrap :)

Comment: @Javaish I guess i do not understand anymore what you need here ? is the image suppose to be same width as innerwrapper when wrapping ? alike https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bRzbgx ? test with different image sizes

Comment: The images can vary from a few hundre pixels in width to take up the whole width... if they take up so much with that the wrapper would be less than lets say 300pixels then it should flex wrap wrap :) its a bit hard to explain

Comment: @Javaish i get lost, where min-width:300px does the job (ex: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RgvbYM where min-width is only applied to img ) else mix XXpx for img and XXpx for innerwrapper for a total of 600px to force wrapping

Comment: Its the wrapper that should have a min width :) not the image :D

Comment: @Javaish okay, did you test the min-width where you need it to check if min-width is efficient or not ?

Comment: I think i got it now, thanks for showing i modified it a bit and it is now perfectly fine, thanks alot